# Why can I apply a null-conditional operator to a hardcoded string?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2015, null-conditional-operator

I have a `bool` variable like this:

```
bool myBool = true;
```

If I write `if (myBool == null)` I get the following warning:

> The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool?'.

That's clear to me because it doesn't make sense to check whether a non-nullable variable is null. Visual Studio notices that and marks as warning.

Now I have a `string`, which is nullable by default, as I know.

Why can I apply a null-conditional operator to a hardcoded `string` without Visual Studio noticing it? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
"This is a string"?.AnyStringMethod();
```

Shouldn't Visual Studio notice that this `string` isn't null at all?

Comment: Your `bool` example is the compiler telling you something about the type.  Your `string` example would require the compiler to tell you something about the value.

Comment: @juharr `if (5 == 4)` is all about values and is no different from the OP's question where he's specifically talking about a literal `string`, a value the compiler can perfectly reason about at compile time (it already does interning the value to begin with).

Comment: @InBetween I was just pointing out the difference between the examples, not stating that the compiler can not consider values when generating warnings.

Comment: @juharr And what is the point of pointing out the difference if it isn't to justify why one warning is given and the other is not (*"Your `string` example **would** require..."*)? I don't agree with your reasoning, the warning is not given due to other reasons.

Comment: @InBetween It was to point out that there is no reason to assume that because of the first example that the second should follow.  Really the quesiton should have just been "Why don't I get a warning for `"This is a string"?.AnyStringMethod();`?"

Comment: @juharr Yes that is absolutely true, fair point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio must go off the **type** that the operator is working with.

When you create a `bool`, there is no way that it could ever be null by the type, until you change that type to `bool?`.

However, with a hard coded string, even though it has text within the quotes, there's no guarantee that it will stay there. The "variable" that gets created (even as just a plain string) is still of type `string`, which is able to have a `null` assigned to it and not change the type.

What you are looking for would be for them to inspect the value of every variable that they are creating. If they were to do that, then why not also check for something like this?

```
var i = 0;

if (i > 2) // This will always be false!
```

**Update**

As [InBetween](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767890/inbetween) mentioned in the comments, there is a bit of an oversight in here as well. Having a string such as `"Some string"` that is not assigned in a variable is functionally equivalent to `const string s = "Some string";`. If you were to declare it like that, the code inspectors will detect if you run a comparison on that, such as the following:

```
const string s = "Some String";
if (s == null) // This will give a warning that this can't happen
```

I would attribute that difference in the way that the `const` is handled versus the way a plain static string is handled could be attributed to different development teams working on different parts at different times. Again, this is such an edge case that doesn't cause huge problems that it doesn't get warned that no one working on it most likely didn't think about it.

Comment: Well the argument here is that its a literal `string` which the compiler normally processes in a diferent way (`string` interning) from normal variables typed `string`. So theoretically it could issue a warning in this case. The main reason it doesn't is that the code is completely pointless (probably no one thought about it) and more importantly, harmless.

Comment: The question wasn´t about the integer as your code shows, but rather about the string and the difference of the value type versus the reference type.

You get a plus though for showing how to make a variable nullable

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari You're absolutely correct. The code that I showed was a parallel of what the OP was asking for. The text of my answer was explaining my answer to their question. Just because it's in a code block doesn't mean it is the crux of the answer, when the question is not a code-specific question.

Comment: @InBetween Does ReSharper or the Visual Studio code sense work off the compiled code, or just what is written? I think going off the IL would be even more resource intensive than the coverage tools already are. I could see them using that as guide to "hey this would be interpreted differently", but not on what is actually generated. I agree with you about the edge-case situation here, but I'll still present a case that the type that is being operated on is still `string`, regardless of whether or not an actual variable gets created.

Comment: @krillgar I dont exactly agree. An interned `string`, IIRC is basically equivalent to a `const string`; the compiler *will* detect unreachable code in the following case: `const string s = "HELLO"; if (s == null) return; //unreachable code detected` so it stands to logic to think that the compiler could issue the warning the OP is asking about with little effort (another matter is if its useful, which it clearly is not).

Comment: @InBetween Ah, cool. That's not something that I'd run into, and didn't think of. So I stand corrected. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Warnings are for code that *looks right but is actually wrong*.

Your code *looks wrong but does the right thing anyways*.

Therefore: no warning.

Comment: Short but succinct. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Because no one thought about it? Your code is so pointless that probably no one foresaw it would ever be used in production code. I'm pretty sure this scenario didn't even crop up once in the C# design comittees although I'd take that with a grain of salt until someone like Eric Lippert sheds more light on the issue.

C# sharp isn't born with all potential features and then someone decides to prune it. In order for the compiler to give a certain warning someone has to think about it, implement it, test it and document it.

In case of `myBool == null`, the warning is justified becuase its a plausible error that could potentially make it into production code and its clearly a bug in the program's logic. The second scenario is completely harmless even if it ends up making it into production, so the warning really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Normally I don't use `string` methods like this. But I wrote an extension method that shows a `MessageDialog` with the defined text. So in my program I can just write `"This is a message.".ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because bool is of a value type while string is a reference type

Value types cannot be null, but reference types are automaticly nulled through Default

The reason Visual Studio doesn´t notice, is because it is of no importancable really.. it is like asking if blue is more of a color than green

Answer (score 0):

A string literal is slightly different than a string object. I believe the string literal is basically like a constant, it is immutable, and will not ever be null.

When you assign a string literal to a variable, you are creating a reference to the string in a memory location. That reference can be null. If you try to concatenate your string variable with another string and store back in your original string variable, the original string in memory is destroyed and a new string is created that is the concatenated string. This is because strings are always immutable.